# setAttribute function in a-animations attributes with a-frame does not work

Tags: aframe

i tried so far changing a-animation element attributes in a-frame like :

```
   setAttribute('dur',5000);
```

or

```
   setAttribute('to',{x: 0, y: 0, z: 1});
```

but it never play the animation and the type of value is [object Object], i tried also setting the stringified value of vec3  type like 'x y z' but it never play with the new updated values in the browser !

Answer (score 1):

`<a-animation>` doesn't do parsing like components do. So you'd have to do `setAttribute('to', '0 0 1')` as a string.

Comment: i tried `setAttribute('to', '0 0 1')` it modify the dom element but it never do the job, it take always the first defined value at `<a-animation>`.

Comment: https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-animation-component might be more friendly to updates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
setAttribute('to',{x:0; y:0; z:1});
```

?